# How using sans-serif font for ticks while using LaTeX Computer Modern font for math expressions in a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts, latex

When using `rc('text', usetex=True)`, everything looks very well (sans-serif font for labels and Computer Modern font for equations in label text) except for the ticks. Ticks are in Computer Modern font and I'd like to have sans-serif font for ticks.

One solution I've found is to use `mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{sansmath}', r'\sansmath']`. This correctly put ticks in sans-serif font. However, it also affects equations which I don't want.

An second solution is to use `ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter()._usetex = False`. This correctly put ticks in sans-serif font and doesn't affect equations. However, it doesn't work for log-scale axis. I managed to fix this problem using `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FormatStrFormatter('%.e'))`. However, ticks are no more in the format "10^x".

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8

import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

mpl.rc('text', usetex=True) # Let TeX do the typsetting

if False:
    mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{sansmath}',
                                           r'\sansmath']

# Data
a = np.arange(24).reshape(6,4)/1.
x = np.arange(7)
y = np.array((1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000))

# Figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
pc = plt.pcolormesh(x, y, a.T, cmap=mpl.cm.viridis)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
plt.title(r"\textit{This} \underline{is the} \textbf{title}", fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel(r"This is the $x$ axis $D_x$ (\textmu m)", fontsize=9)
plt.ylabel(r"\textit{\underline{This}} is the $y$ axis $P_y$ (km)", fontsize=9)
cbar.set_label(label=r"Colorbar $R'_T=\frac{b}{a}$ (\%)", fontsize=9)
plt.text(2, 50, r'\textbf{Sample Text}', fontsize=20, color='w')

# Tick param
ax.set_yscale('log')
if True:
    ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter()._usetex = False
    ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter()._usetex = False
    cbar.ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter()._usetex = False
if False:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FormatStrFormatter('%.e'))
```

The resulting image from this code:
[image]

Is there a much simpler way to use sans-serif font for ticks while using Computer Modern font for equations in label?

Comment: Do you want/need to use latex or is using latex part of the workaround for your problem? Some relevant discussion is in [#12856](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12856).

Comment: I want to use latex. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I've found that I can also use `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())` for values greater than 1. However, I really want to get ticks with the "10^x" format.